# Moving Rows Up and Down in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

So right now, I can select rows and move it up and down. Here is the event listener:

```
    $(".moveUpPlaylist").click(function () {
        moveSelected("up");
    });

    $(".moveDownPlaylist").click(function () {
        moveSelected("down");
    });
```

And here is the actual functions:

```
function moveSelected(direction){
        var arr = jQuery('#table_playlist tbody tr.row_selected');

        for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {            
            var tr = arr[i];            
            var row = jQuery(tr);               // row to move.

            var prevRow;
        if(direction === "up")
            prevRow = jQuery(tr).prev();
        else
            prevRow = jQuery(tr).next();

        /* already at the top? */
        if(prevRow.length==0){  break; }    

        moveDataUp(row, prevRow);
        moveVisualSelectionUp(row, prevRow);
    }   
}   

/* the visual stuff that show which rows are selected */
function moveVisualSelectionUp(row, prevRow){
    row.removeClass("row_selected");
    prevRow.addClass("row_selected");
}

/* move the data in the internal datatable structure */
function moveDataUp(row, prevRow){      
    var movedData = _tablePL.fnGetData(row[0]).slice(0);    // copy of row to move.
    var prevData = _tablePL.fnGetData(prevRow[0]).slice(0); // copy of old data to be overwritten by above data.

    // switch data around :)
    _tablePL.fnUpdate(prevData , row[0], 0, false, false);  
    _tablePL.fnUpdate(movedData , prevRow[0], 0, true, true);
}
```

So the problem lies when I move rows down to the bottom of the page. It can only move within the same page of the table. How can I make it so it will move across pages if its at the bottom or top of a page?

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure this is past being useful to the originator of the post but maybe it can be useful to others. I found it easier to pull the data out of the table, update the array accordingly and redraw the table. To have this work for me I had the index set as an attribute on the up/down buttons to tie them to the specific row.

```
$(document).on('click', '.moveup', function(e){
    var index = $(this).attr('index');
    if ((index-1) >= 0) {
        var datatable = $('#datatable.table').dataTable()
        var data = datatable.fnGetData();
        datatable.fnClearTable();
        data.splice((index-1), 0, data.splice(index,1)[0]);
        datatable.fnAddData(data);
    }
});
$(document).on('click', '.movedown', function(e){
    var index = $(this).attr('index');
    if ((index+1) >= 0) {
        var datatable = $('#datatable.table').dataTable()
        var data = datatable.fnGetData();
        datatable.fnClearTable();
        data.splice((index+1), 0, data.splice(index,1)[0]);
        datatable.fnAddData(data);
    }
});
```

By redrawing the entire table you don't run into pagination issues

Comment: Hello... Can You Please Post Your Html Code!! it would be great Help :)